# Why zeros of a quadratic equations are said roots?

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology, roots, quadratics

What does roots of a quadratic equations signifies?

Why quadratic equations's zeros are said roots?Do roots means something else also with the x intercept?

Comment: Culture corner: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/520491/where-does-the-mathematical-use-of-the-word-root-come-from

Comment: @JeanMarie Who knew that $x=-1(\implies x^2=1)$ and a radish have the same, uhm, root?

Comment: @Ryan G Excellent pun. Too few humor on math SE...

Comment: Super cool post @JeanMarie, but it only describes how the term root is linked to the "root of a number", fx. square roots. I'm guessing a "root of a polynomial" could mean something like a generelized root (as one could naively assume that all polynomial roots could be expressed in radicals)?

Comment: @Richard Jensen Indeed, it is possible that the primitive usage of the word "root" could be square root, cubic root, and then, as early algebraists discovered that the various processes involved for solving polynomial equations were involvin roots "extraction" (for the quadratics), roots of expressions involving themselves roots (for the 3rd degree, at least in some cases... as you remark), etc. they kept the word "root" for polynomials zeros.

Answer (score 2):

"Zero" and "root" are often used interchangeably, particularly in complex analysis. This is true not just for quadratics, not just polynomials, but all functions whose codomain includes zero.

Comment: And $x$-intercept also means the same thing.

Comment: BTW, is it technically correct to speak of roots of an equation (like how we speak of roots/zeros of functions)? Or is “solutions” (pedantically) preferred when referring to equations?